# Need to generate same ciphertext everytime

Tags: encryption

I am developing in android and working with numeric ids. Say for e.g., `5001`.

I upload videos with this id prefixed in in the uploaded video's name.

For e.g. `5001_profile_video.mp4` is a filename. Then if `5001` gets encrypted to `xx841jf==`, the file name would be `xx841jf==_profile_video.mp4`.

I need this to be same every time. Say I uploaded video for profile id `5001`, the and the file name was `xx841jf==_profile_video.mp4`. Then, next time I retrieve video for id `5001` I should be able to form part of  the file name as `xx841jf==` for retrieving video from server.

I need to encrypt `5001` but I need it to be same every time I call the encrypt method. I am currently using Cipher class in java but the results are different every time.

What should I do? Is encryption what I should be looking for OR should I look for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the Cipher class is concerned, most modes include a random IV, which would create this problem.  I can think of two solutions:

1. Use Cipher in ECB (Electronic Code Book) mode.  This is normally discouraged because it does produce the same output for if the key/data are the same, but that is what you want here.
2. Since you don't seem to need the ability to reverse the process (take "xx841jf==" and get back 5001), I would take a look at a hash like SHA-256 or something similar.  If it produces a prefix that is too long you can choose to take the first ___ bits and ignore the rest of the hash output.

Comment: Please note that I explicitly warned against the direct use of a hash over the number because of brute force attacks on the input of the hash in my answer.

Comment: I got the result I wanted using Cipher in ECB mode using a key stored  in application. Thanks. I am now able to encrypt and decrypt the uid value correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a small value such as `xx841jf==` to retrieve a video then a hacker can simply brute force the URL by iterating over all the values. Similarly, if you use a hash over the number (5001) then the attacker can simply go over all numbers, perform the hash and perform the same attack.

There are a few good options for doing this:

1. Use a block cipher to encrypt the number value. In that case you need to pad the encoded number to a full block (using bit padding or PKCS#7 padding, for instance) and then the *full* result. This can be reversed to the number by the server.
2. Similarly you can use a hash over the number and a secret value (a pepper) to calculate a unique number, and then take the leftmost bits in case you want to shorten the URL (you'd still want at least 64 bits otherwise you may mistakenly reuse hash output values).
3. Often unique, large, random ID (a UID) is used to link to the number.

---

Notes:

- For the first option you could use a 64 bit block cipher (e.g. Blowfish) or a 128 bit cipher such as AES. AES is more secure, but the URL will be much larger.
- If direct encryption with the block cipher is not available then you could choose AES in ECB mode using PKCS#7 padding which is commonly available.
- Of course you'd need to *keep a table for the last two options*, otherwise you cannot reverse the URL to the number and thus filename.
- Instead of using standard base 64 encoding you could have a look at base-64-url encoding, which is URL-safe and thus doesn't require URL escaping.

Comment: You can of course also use session state instead of a specific URL encoding to allow access to specific resources. That's not crypto, but it may be a good idea to keep other options in mind.

Comment: Hacker $\neq$ cracker. (1) Does not need padding unless this padding is all-zero and used as an authenticator. (2) needs at least 96 bits to not collide with reasonable chance, or 128 to be conservative. Worse, you'd still need to have some collision resolution. (3) is good, so long that timing access doesn't leak information about what is and isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

For encrypted communication it is undesirable for two messages to leak any information about their content. The same plaintext mapping to the same ciphertext  obviously leaks the fact that $M_i$ and $M_j$ are equal because $E_K(M_i) = E_K(M_j)$. To get around this problem protocols employ a nonce (number used only once). Or they re-key for every message.

Block ciphers are deterministic one-to-one (specifically bijective) functions and so they normally need to use a [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) with a nonce. So to get the same result every time you need to use the same key and use the same initialization values. (You can no longer call it a nonce if you use it twice with the same key.)

If you want to use a library that does most of the crypto for you and you want this type of determinsiic mapping, then have to specify you want to use ECB mode with no padding. Then you want to encrypt exactly the number of bytes in one block for that cipher. Sixteen bytes for AES for example.

(Note to readers that stumble upon this post via search engine: **Don't** use ECB under normal circumstances, including communications and file storage. Be especially careful if you decide you need ECB **not to use more than one block**. ECB does not turn a 128-bit-block-size cipher into a 256-bit-block-size cipher. Instead it encrypts the blocks the same way in 128 bit chunks and then joins the encrypted block values back together. Use a bigger block cipher instead, like ThreeFish.)

---

**Alternatives** specific to this type of application

- If you want obfuscation without security then use MurmurHash's 64 bit finalizer with a counter starting from 1. Or use Java's SplittableRandom with a seed. (Use all 64 bits from nextLong().) Giving you up to $2^{64}$ non-coliding IDs before they repeat. If you need a different block size then consider Speck (which has many insecure blocksize/keysize combinations). Or an LCG (weak non crypto PRNG).
- If you want to evenly distribute files like in a hash table or to different caches than use SipHash or HMAC serverside with a random and secret 128 bit key. (Or client side if you instead want to keep secrets from the server.) Do **not** give the same key to different users if done client side.
- Hash your file, filename, identifier, or whatever with a collision/preimage resistant hash. (Not SipHash. Not Murmur.) Don't truncate the output length so low that [birthday effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) collisions happen. You can assume a 256 bit output from a secure hash function is collision free if it resists collision attacks. (Beware length extension problems. If you want to hash with a secret key then use HMAC or a SHA-3 finalist or Blake2.)
- Generate random IDs and keep a database of the mapping. Check for duplicates. This can't be done offline, but you can start with short IDs (leaking some time metadata) and grow as needed and there's no way for attackers or malicious employees to predict future ID's if database or key secrecy is breached.

---

**Generic concerns**

- If your "encrypted" ID has $n$ in bits and you have $N$ videos then an attacker can guess and check URLs for any valid URL with $N \over 2^n$ probability.
- If your ID has length $n$ in bits and an attacker is looking for a specific video, they have $2^{-n}$ probability.
- With no key or a shared key, people could guess the input to a hash / deterministic cipher / permutation function (say a number, the word "admin", a short string, or a publicly available file) then they can compute the output and query your server to look for it. You don't want to leak private data. (Hashed email addresses, for example, are easily reversed because they have low entropy inputs. Same for weak passwords.)
- Encrypting / hashing filenames is not an alternative to authentication. If you must deliver content via a static-content HTTP server and can't do authentication then use a different long random string for each file as part of the file path. As many bits of entropy as you can fit in a URL up to 256 bits. Disable indexing features that enumerate all filenames. It's better to use a random string, but if you must use the output of hash content (or whatever) then it's not so bad. If someone finds a hash that works then presumably they found it because they already knew the entire contents. As long as it's not linked to user IDs or personal information.

Related: [The Comprehensive Guide to URL Parameter Encryption in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)  which contains some good lessons.